# How can I get the local calendar after log in iCloud account？

Tags: ios, calendar

I met a problem when using the `iOS Calendar(EventKit)`. My Calendar Event is created and stored in the `EKEventStore`(Type is `EKSourceTypeLocal`), when I login `iCloud` account, I can't get the event witch I created before.

Sure,when I login `iCloud`,It said that I can merge my local device data to `iCloud` `Clendar`,if I choose `YES`,the local device data will be merged in `iCloud`,Then I can find my event using event type '`EKSourceTypeCalDAV`',But I don't want sync it to my `iCloud` calendar.

I can't find my local event anywhere(If don't merge to `iCloud`)..please help,thanks!

Comment: Show what have you done

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)isICloudAccountLogin {
    for (EKSource *tempSource in self.eventStore.sources) {
        if (tempSource.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV && [tempSource.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"]) {
            EKSource *localSource = [self sourceInEventStore:[EventManager getInstance].eventStore sourceType:EKSourceTypeCalDAV sourceTitle:@"iCloud"];
            NSArray *calendarArray = [self getAllCategoryOfCalendarBySource:localSource andCalendarType:EKCalendarTypeCalDAV andEventType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
            if ([calendarArray count] <= 0) {
                return NO;
            }
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

I use this code to check if iCloud Account has login.And handle other process in different EKSource.