# Does iOS allow local calendars and iCloud to coexist?

Tags: ios, iphone, calendar

I want to create a calendar app for iOS that manages and syncs its own calendars.

For that I intend to create local calendars on the device which are not synced with iCloud or any other datasource but mine.

I have looked at similar StackOverflow questions, e.g.

- [How can I get the local  calendar after log in iCloud account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562135/how-can-i-get-the-local-calendar-after-log-in-icloud-account)
- [Local Calendar disappearing in iOS 10.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41976135/local-calendar-disappearing-in-ios-10-2-1)

and it seems as if local calendars that are created programmatically do not show up in iOS system calendars when iCloud is enabled? Is this assumption correct?

Unfortunately I don't have XCode or an iPhone at hand to test, yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local calendar which can sync with iCloud.

Please take a look at following project. In which it creates calendar locally if it doesn't exist.

https://github.com/sojitrajay/JSCalendar

You can see local calendars when iCloud is enabled in the device.

Comment: Jayesh, thanks. In the `calendarWithName` method in your code it seems you pick an iCloud calendar source, if the first source is CalDAV. Otherwise it loops within the same loop iteration until if find a local calendar source (nested for). Is that intentional? In any case, it seems as if you use iCloud and only fall back to local calendars if iCloud is not enabled.

Comment: Yes, It's there intentionally for iCloud calendar. If it doesn't find iCloud calendar then it will create local calendar which can be seen in the iCal. You can remove that portion of code if you don't want iCloud.